# How can I display the Native client window in a background page, on a chrome.app.window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-nativeclient, google-chrome-app

I've built a packaged application for Chrome using the portable native client (pNaCL) libraries.  Since my application uses sockets to communicate with a service on the network, I want that communication to be persistent when the main window for the application is closed.  To manage this, I set up the background.js file for my application to create the  tag for the pnacle modules.  The service connections work great running in the background and everything appears to be happy.   Now, under certain conditions, my application needs to show information to the user.   For pictures and content, I simply open a chrome.app.window and post a message with the content, but because sometimes this information is video, it doesn't seem to make sense to stream the information over the network to the pnacl module in the background page, then stream it again to the popup window.   Using the 2D pepper APIS, I can paint the video frames directly into the pnacl modules display area (the  tag), however because that area exists inside the background page, it's not visible to the user.  (fwiw background pages cannot be made visible)

Is there an efficient way to somehow link or show the  area from the background page, in the pop up window?

(NOTE: I've left out the listeners and message handlers since they're quite verbose and wont' give much useful information.)

Also note that I'm quite familiar with the various video streaming tools and API's.  This video format is proprietary to the service software I'm connecting to, and I am required to decode it manually in my pNaCL module.

```
Sample manifest:

{
    "name": "__MSG_packageName__",
    "short_name":  "__MSG_packageShortName__",
    "version": "1.2.3.4",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "minimum_chrome_version": "36.0",
    "description": "__MSG_packageDescription__",
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        { "socket": [ "tcp-connect:*:*", "resolve-host" ] },
        "fullscreen",
        "system.network",
        "alwaysOnTopWindows",
        "https://accounts.google.com/*",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/*"
    ],
    "icons": { "16": "./images/icon16.png",
        "48": "./images/icon48.png",
        "128": "./images/icon128.png" },
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": [ 
                "script/background.js" ],
            "persistent": true
        }
    },
    "default_locale": "en"

}
```

background.js

```
function main ()
{
    var div = document.createElement('div')
    div.setAttribute('id', 'listener');
    var embed = document.createElement( 'embed' );
    embed.setAttribute( 'name', 'nacl_module' );
    embed.setAttribute( 'id', 'student_nacl' );
    embed.setAttribute( 'src', 'student.nmf' );
    embed.setAttribute( 'type', 'application/x-pnacl' );

    div.appendChild( embed );
    document.body.appendChild(g_listener_div);


    connectListeners();

    // show the popup window

    chrome.app.window.create('main.html', {
        'bounds': {
            'width': 400,
            'height': 400,
            'top': 10,
            'left': 10
        }, null );


}

main();
```

Comment: Someone might have a more clever answer, so I'll just make this a comment. No, there isn't any way to make any part of a background page visible. Have you considered breaking the app into two different NaCl modules, one to monitor the network, and the other to render content?

Comment: @sowbug - Thanks for the suggestion.  I have considered that and will probably have to go that route but was hoping for a more clever solution.  I appreciate the help.